# How to get pointer to const pointer to const int from int reference in one line?

Tags: c++

Is there any way I could write the two lines (7 and 8) of code into one line? I think I understand why the error occurs.

```
int value = 5;
   
int &GetValue() { return value; }

int main() {

    const int *my_value = (const int *)&(GetValue());                // 7
    const int *const *my_value_pp = (const int *const *)&(my_value); // 8

    // This gives error for saying cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int *' 
    // const int* const * my_second_value_pp = (const int* const*)(&(&(Getvalue()));
}
```

I need this since there is a function (which I did not write) that takes a `const int *const *` as an argument.

Comment: What is your understanding of why the error occurs?

Comment: u can't take the address of an `rvalue`. u have to create a pointer first to take its address.

Comment: Please don't tell me you're going to write this in one line and then leave it that way permanently in a shared code base somewhere. That's not good for anybody. If this is merely a learning experiment, however, writing this in one line is ok.

Comment: @asmmo so just keep it as it is?

Comment: @pokche Sort of. Remove all the casting. It's not needed. `int const* my_value = &GetValue();` and `int const* const* my_value_pp = &my_value;` - but why do you need this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo ok .. for some reason I thought casting was required. Type casting is not required because it is primitive types or PODs? and it happens implicitly

Comment: @pokche Always start _without_ casting. No, it's not required because you are only adding `const`. You make both stricter than the original. If it had been the other way around, you would need to cast. You could do this: `int* my_value = &GetValue(); int** my_value_pp = &my_value;` without casting. It's what the types are already.

Comment: @pokche It's almost been a full day. Is this question still valid? If not, I suggest that you either remove it or clarify what you need help with.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry I missed your question on - but why do you need this? So to answer this, there is a function which I did not write takes `const int *const *` as argument. Since the function take that argument, I had to convert it to that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the two lines does not require casting, so just write:

```
const int* my_value = &GetValue();         // 7
const int* const* my_value_pp = &my_value; // 8
```

You can however not write that as a one-liner as the function you are going to call needs the address of `my_value`. You can however skip `my_value_pp` and call your function using `my_value` directly:

```
void func(const int* const*) {} // example function taking a  const int* const*
func(&my_value);                // &my_value  is a  const int**
```